# How to make ostream operator for nested list in c++?

Tags: c++, list, class, nested, ostream

```
  class CTurist
{
private:
    string name;
    string country;
    int age;
public:
    CTurist()
    {
        name = "";
        country = "";
        age = 0;
    }
    CTurist(string n, string c, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        country = c;
        age = a;
    }
    CTurist(const CTurist &t)
    {
        name = t.name;
        country = t.country;
        age = t.age;
    }
    string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    string get_country()
    {
        return country;
    }
    int get_age()
    {
        return age;
    }
    void set_name(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    void set_country(string c)
    {
        country = c;
    }
    void set_age(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }
    bool operator<(CTurist& t)
    {
        return this->age < t.age;
    }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, CTurist& t)
    {
        istr >> t.name >> t.country >> t.age;
        return istr;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const CTurist& t)
    {
        ostr << "\nName: " << t.name << ", country: " << t.country << ", age: " << t.age;
        return ostr;
    }

};

class CHotel
{
private:
    string hotel_name;
    int num_beds;
    double aver_price;
    list<list<CTurist>>l;
public:
    CHotel()
    {
        hotel_name = "";
        num_beds = 0;
        aver_price = 0;
    }
    CHotel(string hn, int nb, double ap, list<list<CTurist>>&lis)
    {
        hotel_name = hn;
        num_beds = nb;
        aver_price = ap;
        l = lis;
    }
    CHotel(const CHotel& h)
    {
        hotel_name = h.hotel_name;
        num_beds = h.num_beds;
        aver_price = h.aver_price;
    }
    string get_hotel_name()
    {
        return hotel_name;
    }
    int get_num_beds()
    {
        return num_beds;
    }
    double get_aver_price()
    {
        return aver_price;
    }
    list<list<CTurist>> get_list_name() {
        return l;
    }
    void set_hotel_name(string hn)
    {
        hotel_name = hn;
    }
    void set_num_beds(int nb)
    {
        num_beds = nb;
    }
    void set_aver_price(double ap)
    {
        aver_price = ap;
    }
    bool operator<(CHotel& h)
    {
        return this->aver_price < h.aver_price;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const CHotel& h)
    {
        ostr << "Hotel name: " << h.hotel_name << ", number of beds: " << h.num_beds << ", average price: " << h.aver_price;
        for(list<list<CTurist>>::iterator itr=h.l.begin();itr!=h.l.end();itr++)
        {
            for (list<CTurist>::iterator it = itr->begin(); it != itr->end(); it++)
                ostr << *it;
        }
        return ostr;
    }
```

}

As you see i have this 2 classes-CTurist and CHotel.

Everything with the first one is ok, but the problems came with the second.

I'm trying to make ostream operator for class CHotel works.

Everything else is working but only this operator is the problem.

I'm sure it is because of the nested list cuz it is new for me and maybe im somehow wrong.

### If anyone knows how to do it, please tell me where is my mistake.

```
<br>And this is the error when im trying to debug it.It sure is from this nested list.

error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' 1> with 1> [ 1> _Ty=std::list<CTurist,std::allocator<CTurist>> 1> ]
```

Comment: Have you overriden `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const CTurist&)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 error C2440: 'initializing' (this is the line of first for loop in ostream operator)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, i haven't. The ostream operator for the CTurist class is different and it is working, but this one for class CHotel is not.

Comment: please include the full error message in the question. C2440 is compiler specific and of little help not knowing what compiler you use and "initializing" isnt the full message

Comment: @Jarod42 yes it exists in CTurist class.

Comment: maybe it is because `h` is a const reference but you try to get a non-const iterator, but that is just a guess. Please include a [mcve] and the error

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::list<CTurist,std::allocator<CTurist>>
1>        ]

Answer (score 4):

As `h` is a `const CHotel&`, you need `const_iterator`:

```
for (list<list<CTurist>>::const_iterator itr=h.l.begin();itr!=h.l.end();itr++)
{
    for (list<CTurist>::const_iterator it = itr->begin(); it != itr->end(); it++)
        ostr << *it;
}
```

Or simply use *for range*:

```
for (const auto& turists : h.l)
{
    for (const auto& turist : turists)
        ostr << turist;
}
```